# Is it possible to set "before_all" for single scenarios in behave?

Tags: python, selenium, gherkin, python-behave

I'm new in bdd. Couldn;t find the answer so came here. I want to implement python behav bdd testing with project object model implemented. I'm gonna have 2 objects. Also I'm gonna have one feature with two scenarios. I would like to setUp different object to each scenario. Is something like that possible ?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, you could do that in the `before_scenario` function in the `environments.py` file.

Comment: @LeviNoecker I could basically create two different context.variables but I was curious if there is any another way

Comment: Not necessarily related to your question, but input parameterization can be done with Scenario Outlines (aka *Example blocks*), as seen in https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#scenario-outlines